# What's wrong with my JPA DAO? It will persist but there's an error on merge

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, openjpa

I'm using JPA and EJBs on WebSphere 7.

I have the following class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="WIDGET")
public class Widget implements Serializable {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
  private String name;
  private String details;
/* getters and setters */
}
```

I have a DAO like so:

```
@Stateless
public class WidgetDAO implements WidgetDAOLocal {
  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory emf;
  private EntityManager em;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    if (emf == null) {
      throw new Exception();
    }
    return emf.createEntityManager;
  }

  public Widget getWidget(Long id) {
    Widget widget = null;
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
      widget = (Widget)em.find(Widget.class, widgetId);
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
    return widget;
  }

  public Widget createWidget(Widget widget) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
      em.persist(widget);
      em.flush();
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
    return widget;
  }

  public Widget updateWidget(Widget widget) {
    EntityManager em = getEntityManager();
    try {
      widget = getEntityManager().merge(widget);
      em.flush();
    } finally {
      em.close();
    }
    return widget;
  }

}
```

The create works fine and my widget appears in the database.

But when I try to do a merge, I get an error.  The code to do the merge and the error I get follows:

```
public WidgetService {

  @EJB
  private WidgetDAO widgetDAO;

  public WidgetDAO getWidgetDAO() {
    return this.widgetDAO;
  }

  public Widget getWidget(Long id) {
     return this.getWidgetDAO().getWidget(id);
  }

  public void updateDetails(Long widgetId, String details) {
    Widget w = this.getWidget(widgetId);
    w.setDetails(details);
    this.widgetDAO.updateWidget(w);
  }

}
```

The error is:

```
Exception caught from before_completion synchronization operation: 
<openjpa-1.2.1-SNAPSHOT-r422266:686069 nonfatal user error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.InvalidStateException:
The generated value processing detected an existing value assigned to this field: com.mydomain.domain.Widget.id.  
This existing value was either provided via an initializer or by calling the setter method.  
You either need to remove the @GeneratedValue annotation or modify the code to the initializer processing.
```

Any help on this is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Try adding a @Version column.

Comment: I added @Version column but no luck.  Nice addition, but I get the same error.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It looks like you are setting id somewhere manually... Try to audit id setter calls.

Comment: @kernel_mode Thx, that's what it looks like but I'm literally never calling setId -- the only thing that sets id is the `@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)` annotation.

Comment: @kernel_mode I'm using Oracle (version 11 I think)

Comment: Try using em.refresh() before getting Widget.

Comment: @kernel_mode I don't appear to have a em.refresh() method, I have a em.refresh(entity) method, but if I don't have the widget yet, that can't be right, can it? (Just FYI, I'm using openjpa-1.2.1, comes with WebSphere 7 which is Java EE 5, and is Java Persistence 1.0.)

Comment: @RobertHume You're not showing us the `WidgetService.getWidget(widgetId)` method.  Does that just proxy to the Dao?

Comment: @TimPote Thx, I added the getWidget method for you, it's so simple I left it out.  WidgetService and WidgetDAO are both stateless EJBs -- widgetDAO.createWidget(widget) is working so everything is connected.

Comment: @RobertHume `getWidget(widgetId)`, not `getWidgetDao`.

Comment: @TimPote Sorry, it's in there now too.  Just a one-liner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everybody, I figured it out, here's the cause of the problem and the solution that worked for me.

In my DAO I was doing this:

```
@Stateless 
public class WidgetDAO implements WidgetDAOLocal {
   @PersistenceUnit
   private EntityManagerFactory emf;
   private EntityManager em;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
     if (emf == null) {
       throw new Exception();
     }
     return emf.createEntityManager;
   }
```

Because the EntityManagerFactory was being injected via the @PersistenceUnit annotation, the entities were "Application-Managed", causing some kind of conflict with WebSphere.

I changed the code to this:

```
@Stateless 
public class WidgetDAO implements WidgetDAOLocal {
  @PersistenceContext 
  private EntityManager em;

  public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
    return em;
  } 

  public Widget updateWidget(Widget widget) throws Exception {
    return getEntityManager().merge(widget);
  }
```

The @PersistenceContext annotation causes the entities to be "Container-Managed", and everything works now.

Thanks for the all the help and suggestions here.  At the end of the day, I worked out the solution after re-focusing on the "Managing Entities" section of the documentation here:

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/

Answer (score 0):

Merge takes a copy of your entity, detaches it and persists the new one, which i presume attempts to set the ID from the old and causes you the conflict on your generated values. If you just want to update your object you should do so within a transaction and commit that.

Comment: Ah!  We may be onto something here.  Thx.  Is there an easy way to make the entire updateWidget method a transaction like an @Transaction annotation on the method maybe?

Comment: Doesn't look like it from what I can tell. You'll need to start the transaction through em.getTransaction().begin() do your changes and .commit() them.

Comment: Thx, I won't be able to try it until I get back to the office on Monday.  But I will do it first thing and get back to you.

Comment: I tried `begin` and `commit` like you said, but I get an error: `You cannot access the EntityTransaction when using managed transactions` -- any ideas?

Comment: I got it working, I'll post my answer now.  Thanks for the help!